# Element width of a dropdown not available at document.ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, document-ready

I'm trying to get the width of a dropdown list and set the width of a div accordingly.  The problem is that when I try to get the width of the dropdown it comes up as -2.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ddWidth = $("#drdTypes").width();
  alert(ddWidth);
}

<%=Html.DropDownList("drdTypes", new SelectList(Model.TypeList, "text", "text"))%>
```

If I run that same code in a button I get a reasonable value.  I thought that the DOM was available when document.ready fires.

Comment: The DOM **is** available, but some content, for instance images etc. still has to load before they have width and height. Try using `window.onload` and see what happens.

Comment: if I remember correctly, there is a `load` event. May be not in jQuery itself, but in the DOM model

Comment: I figured out a workaround.  I put a script block at the very end of my page calling a function to do what I need and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#drdTypes').load(function () {
    console.log($(this).width());
});
```

Basically wait for the drop down to load and log the width in the console. Make sure it gets put inside the `ready` callback.

Comment: It doesn't fire. I don't think <select> elements have a load event.